# Emulating a keyboard on Windows

Tags: windows, kernel, low-level

Is there a way(library?) to simulate a keyboard on Windows without having to build a driver for it? I would like to send the "keys" pressed from an application to Windows, as the virtual keyboard does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [keybd_event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646304%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to synthesize keystrokes.

Comment: Can't understand why people are still recommending `keybd_event`. There is a giant warning at the top of the MSDN documentation that says: *"**Note** This function has been superseded. Use `SendInput` instead."*